# Relative Growth rate calculation - Computing GrowthT2-GrowthT1 for all observations

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the Relative growth rate for 13000 trees, for which we have measurements for 9 years.
I would like to calculate the following formula:

## RGR = (ln GrowthT2-ln GrowthT1)/(t2-t1)

so log of growth at time 2 minus log growth at time 1
I could do this for single tree-data.frames, however I could not create a RGR column in the original data.frame
The growth is already transformed with the log function (cvallog).

my dataframe:

```
 Subset1= data[data$Id== 1|data$Id==2,]
 > Subset1
    Id          Tree replicate        cval      cvallog
1    1 A_12N_A1_ABBA      2009 0.029224666 -3.532742212
2    2 A_12N_A2_BEAL      2009 0.007306166 -4.919036573
65   1 A_12N_A1_ABBA      2010 0.317308712 -1.147880124
66   2 A_12N_A2_BEAL      2010 0.459960580 -0.776614488
134  1 A_12N_A1_ABBA      2011 0.653251467 -0.425793129
135  2 A_12N_A2_BEAL      2011 1.040621151  0.039817795
198  1 A_12N_A1_ABBA      2012 0.794725631 -0.229758343
199  2 A_12N_A2_BEAL      2012 2.042820623  0.714331511
262  1 A_12N_A1_ABBA      2013 0.735415424 -0.307319736
263  2 A_12N_A2_BEAL      2013 2.189564416  0.783702627
333  1 A_12N_A1_ABBA      2014 0.942966706 -0.058724303
334  2 A_12N_A2_BEAL      2014 3.135083588  1.142655836
397  1 A_12N_A1_ABBA      2015 0.587495498 -0.531886697
398  2 A_12N_A2_BEAL      2015 3.631681108  1.289695656
463  1 A_12N_A1_ABBA      2016 0.995382216 -0.004628479
464  2 A_12N_A2_BEAL      2016          NA           NA
527  1 A_12N_A1_ABBA      2017 0.951695307 -0.049510351
528  2 A_12N_A2_BEAL      2017 3.394292628  1.222095382
```

this is the code for one tree:

```
Subset1= data[data$Id== 1,]  
###create the t1 and 2 t2 columns

Subset1$t1=Subset1$cvallog # create a t1 column
t2=as.data.frame((Subset1$cvallog)[-1])# remove first observation, crate a   t2 column 
t2= as.vector (rbind (t2,  0))
Subset1$t2 = t2  #add t2 to main data.frame so to  have t1 and t2 on the same row.
replicate_t2=as.data.frame((Subset1$replicate)[-1])# remove first observation, crate a t2 column 
replicate_t2= as.vector (rbind (replicate_t2,  0))
Subset1$replicate_t2 = replicate_t2

#calculate RGR  Relative growth
Subset1$RGR = ((Subset1$t2)- (Subset1$t1))/ ((Subset1$replicate_t2)-Subset1$replicate)  #difference between log values divided by 1 because we have 1 year interval
```

when I try to do this in a loop with the split funtion, I cannot create a final output with all the trees.

```
uniqTree <- (split(data, data$Tree))

for (i in 1:length(uniqTree)){
temp =data[data$Id== i,]
temp$t1=temp$cvallog #create t1 column

t2=as.data.frame((temp$cvallog)[-1]) #create t2 column
t2= as.vector (rbind (t2,  0))
temp$t2 = t2
replicate_t2=as.data.frame((temp$replicate)[-1])# remove first observation, crate a t2_replicate column 
replicate_t2= as.vector (rbind (replicate_t2,  0))
temp$replicate_t2 = replicate_t2


#calculate RGR  Relative growth
temp$RGR  = NULL
temp$RGR  = ((temp$t2)- (temp$t1))  / (temp$replicate_t2-temp$replicate)
print(temp$RGR)
}
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using `dplyr` package

`df %>% arrange(Tree,replicate) %>% 
        group_by(Tree) %>% 
        mutate(rt = (cvallog-lag(cvallog))/(replicate-lag(replicate)))`

where `df`

`df = read.table(text= " Id          Tree replicate        cval      cvallog
1    1 A_12N_A1_ABBA      2009 0.029224666 -3.532742212
2    2 A_12N_A2_BEAL      2009 0.007306166 -4.919036573
65   1 A_12N_A1_ABBA      2010 0.317308712 -1.147880124
66   2 A_12N_A2_BEAL      2010 0.459960580 -0.776614488
134  1 A_12N_A1_ABBA      2011 0.653251467 -0.425793129
135  2 A_12N_A2_BEAL      2011 1.040621151  0.039817795
198  1 A_12N_A1_ABBA      2012 0.794725631 -0.229758343
199  2 A_12N_A2_BEAL      2012 2.042820623  0.714331511
262  1 A_12N_A1_ABBA      2013 0.735415424 -0.307319736
263  2 A_12N_A2_BEAL      2013 2.189564416  0.783702627
333  1 A_12N_A1_ABBA      2014 0.942966706 -0.058724303
334  2 A_12N_A2_BEAL      2014 3.135083588  1.142655836
397  1 A_12N_A1_ABBA      2015 0.587495498 -0.531886697
398  2 A_12N_A2_BEAL      2015 3.631681108  1.289695656
463  1 A_12N_A1_ABBA      2016 0.995382216 -0.004628479
464  2 A_12N_A2_BEAL      2016          NA           NA
527  1 A_12N_A1_ABBA      2017 0.951695307 -0.049510351
528  2 A_12N_A2_BEAL      2017 3.394292628  1.222095382" )`

Comment: in some cases, this calculation returns "inf" and "-inf" as result. Maybe is connected to missing values? can something like na.rm=True included?

Comment: The reason should be that the denominator is zero, which means some trees may have multiple measurements in the same year. If they are errors, correct it first. If not, try to use some rules like taking average,max or min to make it unique based on your research question.

Comment: that's right I did not consider the multiple measurements for each tree. When I remove that it looks good. Thanks